# Order object by keys in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dict that looks like this:

```py
country_info = {
    "population": {
        "usa": "328 millions",
        "brazil": "209 millions",       
        "france": "70 millions"
    },
    "capital": {
        "brazil": "Brasilia",
        "usa": "Washington",
        "france": "Paris"
    },
    "language": {
        "france": "French",
        "usa": "English",
        "brazil": "Portuguese"
    }
}
```

How can I order every object by keys to be the same? It doesnt really matter in which order, as long as they are the same. When I loop through the dict in my flask template, I want the country_info dict to contain the same information but with the same order

```py
country_info = {
    "population": {
        "brazil": "209 millions",
        "france": "70 millions",
        "usa": "328 millions",      
    },
    "capital": {
        "brazil": "Brasilia",
        "france": "Paris",      
        "usa": "Washington"
    },
    "language": {
        "brazil": "Portuguese",
        "france": "French",     
        "usa": "English",
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you would be better off using a class here instead of a `dict`. If you need to use `dict`, you can use `collections.OrderedDict`, which preserves the order of the keys that you insert.

Comment: What is the point of using `dict` then, why not use `list` if the order matters than `key`?

Comment: Reading between the lines, something like this may be your actual [X](http://xyproblem.info)? `for country, population in country_info['population'].items(): print(country, population, country_info['capital'][country], country_info['language'][country])`…? Or a datastructure where the data belonging to one country is grouped together to begin with?

Comment: @gmdev regular `dict` does that too

Comment: @mrmister001 just use a list if you need to keep the data ordered. Otherwise call the keys always in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

Although `list` would be preferred, but since python `dict` is now maintaining order( Python 3.6 onwards) you can try something like

```py
sorted_dict = {k1: dict(sorted(country_info[k1].items(), key=lambda x: x[0])) for k1 in country_info.keys()}
```

```
{'population': {'brazil': '209 millions',
  'france': '70 millions',
  'usa': '328 millions'},
 'capital': {'brazil': 'Brasilia', 'france': 'Paris', 'usa': 'Washington'},
 'language': {'brazil': 'Portuguese', 'france': 'French', 'usa': 'English'}}
```